# trying to check if arraylist is subset of another

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to implement a simple check to see if arraylist is subset of another one.

I have following elements in my two lists,  list1 [ A F K ] and list2 [B A C F K]. list1 has all its elements in list2 so it should return true

i tried using list1.containsAll(list2) but it doesn't give me true.

I tried looping through both the list and if a match is found I empty that position in the first list but it doesn't work as I suppose it suffers from concurrent modification. Here is my code

public static boolean isSubset(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2){

```
    ArrayList<String> subTreeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> mainTreeList = new ArrayList<String>();

        treeCopyToList(t1,subTreeList);
        treeCopyToList(t2,mainTreeList);

        int mainTreeSize = mainTreeList.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < subTreeList.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < mainTreeSize; j++){
            if( subTreeList.get(i).equals(mainTreeList.get(j)) ){
                subTreeList.remove(i);
            }   
        }
    }
    System.out.println(subTreeList);
    return subTreeList.isEmpty();
}
```

Here the subTreeList finally outputs [A]. I know it skips the middle element as when I remove the size element is also modified. How do I go about solving this issue so that I get an empty list finally.

Comment: "i tried using list1.containsAll(list2) but it doesn't give me true." - Why do you think that was?

Comment: Looking at your code...I don't see how it's iterating.  You're instantiating `subTreeList` with an empty `ArrayList`, so I'm not convinced it ever iterates.  That is, unless there's something here you're not sharing; in that case, I'd also encourage you to post the old way you attempted your `containsAll`.

Comment: oops sorry I have not given my complete code. Actually I have a helper method that fills the two lists. I will edit the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which you were using `containsAll` is backwards.

You're trying to determine if `list2` contains all elements in `list1`, not if `list1` contains all elements in `list2`.

Simply reverse it, and it should work for you.

Comment: cool thanks. I somehow also tried to increment a counter when the if condition is true and when the counter reaches the initial list size I return true. 

if( subTreeList.get(i).equals(mainTreeList.get(j)) ){
           counter++;
          } 

 return (counter == subTreeSize);

Comment: I got it solved with what you suggested too but now I am curious as to how I would fix the problem of concurrent modification if I tried doing it by remove method. What should I do to fix it in my initial code?

Comment: @JimZilla Use iterator and remove method on it. But if you have any other questions which are not connected to this question, ask another one.